# Clips pattern matching - starts with

Tags: pattern-matching, clips

I'm trying to match all facts with a value that start a certain set of characters. For example, Say I have facts for different people with their name defined as a slot and I have a rule that needs to apply to everyone whose name starts with a 'd'. Is there any way to do that?

Here's an example of what I've tried

```
(deftemplate person (slot name))
(defrule list-names-starting-with-d
  (person (name ?x&d*))
  =>
  (printout t ?x crlf)
)
```

The asterisk is apparently not the symbol I want, but is there a symbol for this? I've looked all over google and this site and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Patterns don't support regular expressions for matching slot values, but you can achieve the same results this way:

```
CLIPS> 
(deffunction starts-with (?str1 ?str2)
   (eq (str-index ?str1 ?str2) 1))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate person (slot name))
CLIPS> 
(defrule list-names-starting-with-d
   (person (name ?x&:(starts-with d ?x)))
   =>
   (printout t ?x crlf))
CLIPS> (assert (person (name fred)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (person (name david)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (assert (person (name ida)))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (assert (person (name dean)))
<Fact-4>
CLIPS> (run)
dean
david
CLIPS>
```